# Ad control "no ad available"

Tags: windows-phone-7, ads

I'm trying to create an adcontrol for a wp7 application. I've set up my account on pubcenter, waited a couple of days so everything is up and running, and tried it. 
It works fine on the emulator (ads are shown), but on my phone they don't. I've attached to the error event and I get an "no ad available" exception message.

What could be happening here??

[Edit] : some extra info. When I set the "Region format" under region & language in the Settings page for the phone to English, it works. However, if I set it to Spain (Spain - International Sort)     (i'm trying to create a multi region app) then that's when the error happens. Is this a bug in Microsoft ad servers? has anyone experienced this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MS AdControl simply doesn't have good inventory overseas yet.  They don't have an international ad network, yet.  I'm sure this is coming. In the meantime you can try other exchanges like AdMob or MobFox but my experience is the MS control pays the best when it has inventory.

Answer (score 0):

The emulator will show test ads, but when you actually publish your app, if there is nobody willing to pay for an ad (based on whatever criteria), you will get that error.

Comment: they're not test ads, they're actually ads. please take a look at my edited comment.